# How to use V to wake up a designated P?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, concurrency, semaphore

Suppose we have a semaphore s and there are multiple threads waiting for it by calling P(s). Then V(s) would wake up exact one thread among them. Is there a way to wake up a designated thread instead of having the system make the decision? For instance, in the barbershop problem, after each haircut, the barber wants to serve the longest waiting customer, instead of a random one.

Comment: Disregarding the `language-agnostic` tag: `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` has `fairNess` which guarantees first-in first-out. But this not an answer, since designation may be upon another parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a queue to store the P's. that'll let you do it based off of longest wait. If not you could store in a sorted tree based off of whatever paramater you want, and remove when needed.

I think the crux of it would be some sort of ordering mechanism for the P's, which souldn't be too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the semaphore. You would have to use a smart semaphore that creates a queue of waiting threads and signals them in the right order. I think the regular semaphore implementation on Windows doesn't work that way. It just sends a signal to the OS, which in turn sends a signal to any of the waiting threads. It would even make sense if this uses a lifo stack, because that is implemented more easily. 
But it wouldn't be hard to build this yourself by implementing a queue, which could be a linked list, or a cyclic array.

Answer (score 1):

No, not with classical semaphores by themselves. If you want queue-like behavior, you create a queue (with a semaphore, or maybe a couple of them) to protect the queue's shared data structure(s).

The reality is, that while semaphores are theoretically all you need to do synchronization, you'd rarely (never?) write a significant body of real code that just used bare semaphores directly. Most of the time, you build higher-level constructs with (for example) a semaphore to protect that critical data in that construct.